# read Json file using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read a json file using pandas's **read_json** function and i am getting result but not what i want 
My result have first row as a header (Titles) and i want to ignore first row in my result.
Below is my python code.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
result=pd.read_json('dummy_DB_clean.json')
print result
```

I tried pandas's **json_normalize()**  function but did not get desired output.
If anyone of you , come across with this problem, please suggest me the solution. 
Thanks,

Comment: Normally JSON files aren't discussed in terms of rows, can you post the first couple as well as what you want `result` to be?

Comment: Elaborating on the above, JSON is intended for just data and doesn't contain any specific "header" or any other kind of metadata as a CSV or similar would. In other words it's just a notation, not a specific file format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json('dummy_DB_clean.json')
df.drop(df.head(1).index, inplace=True)
print df
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)